# How to downgrade Wampserver PHP?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I see everywhere for downgrade php on wampserver I just have to do left click wamp> php>version> get more>
And dowload the version I want.

But when I do it I arrive on this [page](http://www.wampserver.com/#download-wrapper)  and I don't see any link for download an other php version. I only can download a file php5.2.4.isson this [page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/)

So fine I dowload it on [php.net](http://php.net/releases/) and I unzip the archive in my folder  "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.4"

Next I copy the files wampserver.conf, php.ini and phpForApache.ini from my folder "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12" to the folder "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.4"

And to finish I change in the file php.ini and phpForApache.ini the path :

```
extension_dir = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.4"
```

When I restart wamp I have the 2 versions of php the one I use actualy (5.5.12) and the one I want to instal (5.2.4) but when I choose the 5.2.4 my wamp icon became orange and stay like this I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?

Comment: Yes i have some error when i pass to the php version who work but nothing when i pass the the version i want to make work ... not logic

Comment: PHP 5.2.4 wont run in Apache 2.4.9 as there was no Apache 2.4 linkage when PHP5.2.4 was built. You will also need to install an older version of Apache

Answer (score 11):

To manually install any version of PHP into WAMP you can follow the following steps...

1. Download the binaries from [php.net](https://www.php.net/releases/)
2. Extract all files into a new folder: `C:/wamp/php/php5.4.13` (or whatever the version number is)
3. Copy the `wampserver.conf` file from another PHP folder in wamp to the new folder.
4. Rename `php.ini-development` file to `phpForApache.ini`
5. Restart WampServer by exiting out of Wamp and restarting it)

Note: If you are adding php version 5.6, you need to copy `php5apache2_4.dll` from another php folder in wamp as well otherwise the wamp server wont start.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this answer would have been downvoted given the fact that from what I can tell I answered the question fully, and provided a documented and detailed solution. I would like to know so that I can improve my answers in the future, thanks.

Comment: This also applies if you're adding php version 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Wampserver Activities](https://sourceforge.net/p/wampserver/activity) and download the desired PHP version then run the package to install.
Start the wamp server and try again to left-click wamp> PHP> version > select version

Answer (score 0):

I think best and easiest solution is download older version WAMP ,when installing WAMP you can choose what version of php(default they choose latest version, so attention for that,) do you need, that is work for me. for me need to install to php 7.00 so i tried this wamp 3.2 link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oF1Iqsb5nswVFBEWUGLpelDl1TrK2hre/view?usp=share_link)

these are the php versions
[image]