# Is IonCube 7.2 backwards compatible with IonCube 5.6 PHP code?

Tags: php, magento, php-7.2, ioncube

I can't find anything on this topic.

I'm migrating a 1.7.0.2 CE Magento store to Magento 1.9.4.0 CE, but product page where the encrypted code lives on is completely blank.

There is no output in php / apache error logs.

Also system.log / exception.log are empty too.

I'm running PHP 7.2 and IonCube 7.2 on WAMP. The previous working setup was PHP 5.6, IonCube 5.6.

The extension creator is not replying to their email so I'm kind of stuck not knowing if its the encryption of the code or it's my setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Compiled PHP 5.6 code can run on PHP 7.0, but to use on PHP 7 proper, i.e. PHP 7.1 onwards, files need to have been compiled for PHP 7.1. So the extension developer needs to produce files for PHP 7. The ionCube Loader *will* have generated an error message, but PHP logging settings might be masking it or the wrong log file could be being looked at.

Comment: This is probably the answer. Is there a way to trigger error output of IonCube plugin? I'm already outputting Magento errors but, for some reason it just throws a blank page.

Comment: If installed the Loader would have produced an error similar to the following, but where this would appear will depend on your setup:
`PHP Fatal error:  The file blah.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.6 and cannot run under PHP 7.1 or later.
 Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for PHP 7.1.`.

Comment: I got an official response from Ioncube: https://forum.ioncube.com/viewtopic.php?t=4513&start=0

Comment: "The error will be logged at some point depending on what the PHP ini settings of error_log and error_reporting are. 

The most likely problem is that files produced by the PHP 5.6 encoder will not run on PHP 7.2. They will need to be encoded by either the 7.1 or 7.2 encoders. 

There is a feature in the 10.2 ionCube PHP Encoder package called bundling that allows a single set of files to be produced that will run on PHP 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3. 

Anyway, you will need to contact the plugin provider to ask them for an encoded version of their plugin that will run on PHP 7.2."

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by downgrading PHP version of WAMP. And IonCube Loader backwards compatible with older versions of Ioncube Encoder. I would suggest you to download latest version of IonCube Loader. 
[How to downgrade PHP version of WAMP? (Chris Rutherfurd's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939555/how-to-downgrade-wampserver-php)